# Round trip time (sliding window)?

Tags: networking, sliding-window, roundtrip

I have 2 questions:

1. While calculating RTT, should we take transmission time into consideration or not?
2. The distance between two stations M and N is L kilometers. All frames are K bits long. The propagation delay per kilometers is t seconds. Let T bits/sec be the channel capacity. Assuming that processing delay is negligible, what is the minimum number of bits for the sequence number field in a frame for maximum utilization, when the sliding window protocol is used?

Comment: RTT of what? TCP segments? Ethernet packets? Frame relay frames? ATM packets?

Answer (score 1):

1) RTT is the measured time from segment transmission until ACK received. So transmission time will be considered obviosly. One can ignore the retransmission time.

Answer (score 0):

RTT is calculated by considering the values of propagation delay, queing delay, transmission delay and processing delay..

Rtt = 2*[propagation delay + N(queing delay+transmission delay+processing delay)]